# why does the *#uniqueID selector exist if the ID attribute is supposed to be unique?

Tags: html, css

I understand that there is a `*.className` selector since there can be multiple html elements with class=className.

But for the ID attribute which should be unique, why does `*#` exist and when do we use it?

Thanks.

Comment: So you think that `*.className` and `.className` produce different results?

Comment: `html div{}` "exists" too but doesn't make much sense either, and neither does `* *{}`. Where did you see `*#id` being used? My point is that just because it's valid CSS doesn't mean it makes sense or is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because IDs are supposed to be unique doesn't mean they are. You can create multiple elements with the same ID, but you shouldn't. CSS doesn't care anyway, lack of uniqueness would just screw with Javascript. For example, if you have this:

```
<div id='blah'>blah</div>
<div id='blah'>blah</div>
<div id='blah'>blah</div>
<div id='blah'>blah</div>
```

Then `jQuery('#blah')` returns `[ div#blah ]`, whereas `jQuery('*#blah')` returns `[ div#blah, div#blah, div#blah, div#blah ]`.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/72rRn/)

Comment: Whoa! Now that is interesting. I wonder why jQuery implemented it like that. In CSS, there is no difference between `#foo` and `*#foo`...

Comment: I would guess that with a selector of '#blah' jQuery just takes a shortcut and uses document.getElementById, but with '*#blah' it actually searches through the elements. Also possible that they implemented it this way for exactly this reason. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `*` matches **any** element, not *all* elements. It is called the **universal selector**

So `*#myid` matches any element with id equals myid. In CSS, it does not really matter and it is equivalent to `#myid`.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector)

Answer (score 1):

Combining the universal selector with the ID, class, or attribute selectors makes no difference: `#foo` is the same as `*#foo`, `.bar` is the same as `*.bar`, and `[baz]` is the same as `*[baz]`. Therefore, you don't want to be using the universal selector in these scenarios.